# Keychain Wrapper erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSZeroData _fastCharacterContents]

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I am using the keychain wrapper found here:

https://gist.github.com/1170641

Like this:

.h :

```
    #import "KeychainItemWrapper.h"

    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem;
```

.m:

```
 keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"login" accessGroup:nil];

NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

Then it crashes with:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSZeroData _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dcba60'

**EDIT:**

The crash is no longer present thanks to a user who answered the question but when I retrieve the username or password they are sometimes swaped and I mean 80% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
I'm using kSecValueData but commented out `//#define PASSWORD_USES_DATA` in KeychainItemWrapper.m. Also I started using `resetKeychainItem` instead of trying to override the values myself.

Old Answer:
I had this issue until I changed kSecValueData to kSecAttrService, which can be used for passwords also according to SecItem.h. Now everything seems to work fine (setting and retrieving).

Comment: There is no more crash but now when doing this: password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
    username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
    
    [usernameTF setText:username];
    [passwordTF setText:password];
  The password is put in the username field before when using NSUSerDefaults it wouldn't.

Comment: Error on my part I put both as kSecAttrAccount when the password should be kSecAttrService.

Comment: I advised you incorrectly. I went back to using kSecValueData but commented out the //#define PASSWORD_USES_DATA near the top KeychainItemWrapper. Also I use resetKeychainItem to delete the password. Will Edit my answer.

Comment: Ah ok I will change it. Just what is the difference between these keys?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I think they represent different fields of the things you can store within the keychain. The documentation I've read on them is pretty sparse though.

Comment: Ah could you post a link to the documentation?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898-CH4g-SW7

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by changing this:

```
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

to this:

```
NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[keychainItem objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```